# R VCD: Ternary plot legend

Tags: r, plot, legend, ternary

I have successfully created a ternary plot with the following code:

```
data <- read.csv(file, header=TRUE)
ternaryplot(data[,3:5], scale = 100, 
    pch = 19, cex = 0.4, col = Category,
    dimnames = c("Al", "Mg", "Fe + Ti"),
    labels = c("outside"),
    main = "")
```

However, I am struggling to create a legend for it. As the package has assigned colours based on the category of the sample I cannot simply write out the entire legend by allocating colours manually.
I have tried a few variations of the following but have encountered the error code:

```
grid_legend(0.8, 0.9, pch = 19, col = Category, rownames(Category), title = "Categories")

Error in grid_legend(0.8, 0.9, pch = 19, col = Category, rownames(Category),  : 
  pch and labels not the same length
```

This is the first time I have used the vcd package and would appreciate any help on the subject.
Thanks,
Holly

Comment: Have a look at my package, its based off ggplot2, website is www.ggtern.com

Answer (score 0):

The error is explicit:

```
 pch and labels not the same length
```

So , you should give **pch** argument with the same length as **labels** one, replace pch by :

```
rep(19,nrow(Category))
```